# I want to add my own armature to armature menu

Tags: armature

It would be super useful if I could populate this menu with my own custom rigs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't add your armature design into that menu in particular, there are other ways you could go about doing it.

What I usually do is to save my armature rig in an entirely different file. In the event that I want to use it in another project, I just have to Append the armature over to the project.

Hope this helps :D